# The container gets exited with react app in ECS

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I am running a React App in ECS .The docker image has been created and pushed to ECR through jenkins pipeline.The ECS container gets created through terraform code. But the container gets exited with code 0 and new one starts.This became a loop.When i try creating a container manually with commands from the same image,then the container remains active. When the same image used in ECS EC2 ,the container gets created and exited .
When i check the logs from cloud watch i get the logs as
content not from webpack is served from /app/public
404s will fallback to /

```
enter code here

      FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

      # set working directory
      WORKDIR /app

      # add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
      ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

      # install app dependencies
      COPY package.json ./
      COPY package-lock.json ./
      RUN npm install --silent
      RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

      # add app
      COPY . ./

      # start app
      ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: you are using ecs farget that mean no issue due to memory or cpu resources. if you can check service events and error log you might get some idea. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-tasks-container-exit-issues/

Comment: Thanks for the response,but i am not using fargate.I am using ec2 linux instead. From the cloudwatch logs i am getting as
 content not from webpack is served from /app/public
404s will fallback to /

But when i run a container with the same image by giving the commands manually 
docker run -dit --name -p imagename

The container gets created and stable.But when i automate with ECS(same Image),the container is getting exited.

Comment: i am not 100% sure but look like container process is completing with exit code 0. if you can please add this to ECS : stdin_open: true and check which will keep running container and it will not exit

Comment: adding stdin_open: true, tty: true will be same to running container with `docker run -it`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add (use in docker-compose)

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

since the container is exiting with exit code 0.

it will be equivalent to running the container with the `-it` options.

for **ECS** it should be like

In task configuration click Configure via JSON button. Change pseudoTerminal property to true. `"pseudoTerminal": true`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220129/discussion-on-answer-by-harsh-manvar-the-container-gets-exited-with-react-app-in).